# importing a global class from a namespace of the same name in php

Tags: php, import, namespaces, global-variables

Using namespace in this scenario is totally clear, I create a new namespace called ArrayObject and I use that class for my needs.

```
namespace NamespaceTesting;             

class ArrayObject{

    public $initVal;
    function __construct($a){
        $this->initVal = $a;
    }

    public function append($unusedVal){
        var_dump($this);
    }
} 

$a = new ArrayObject("test");
$a->append("unusedVal");
```

the questioni is, if I want to use the global class of ArrayObject, I thought i should put **use ArrayObject** just before to use my code, but it doesn't work. what's wrong?

```
namespace NamespaceTesting;             

class ArrayObject{

    public $initVal;
    function __construct($a){
        $this->initVal = $a;
    }

    public function append($unusedVal){
        var_dump($this);
    }
} 

// this is not working
use ArrayObject;

$a = new ArrayObject("test");
$a->append("unusedVal");
```

what am I interpreting wrongly? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
namespace NamespaceTesting;        

class ArrayObject{

    public $initVal;
    function __construct($a){
        $this->initVal = $a;
    }

    public function append($unusedVal){
        var_dump($this);
    }
} 

// $a is an ArrayObject from global namespace, not from NamespaceTesting;
$a = new \ArrayObject();
$a->append("unusedVal");
var_dump($a);
```

Comment: so do not I need to write the code `use ArrayObject`? just for knowledge. thank you.

Comment: you can(should) write use \ArrayObject, but here it won't work (you do "new \ArrayObject" instead, as in your case ArrayObject is being declared above. In other circumstances you should generally "use \PDO", "use \ArrayObject", etc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the namespace `NamespaceTesting` and not `ArrayObject` And thus need to call it like so ([Using namespaces](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php))

```
use NamespaceTesting;
```

If you want to use the built in ArrayObject class.. you need to precede it with a slash

```
$a = new \ArrayObject("test");
```

Comment: I'm already in the namespace NamespaceTesting, this `use NamespaceTesting;` does not add anything to my code. I need to use the global namespace for ArrayObject, i do not want to use the namespace NamespaceTesting and my NamespaceTesting\ArrayObject class

Comment: if I add `use \ArrayObject;` it says this _Fatal error: Cannot use ArrayObject as ArrayObject because the name is already in use in C:\......\testNamespace3.php on line 22_

Comment: remove the `use ArrayObject;` part

Comment: if I remove it I found myself in the first scenario presented in the post, and the class ArrayObject i declare on the code `$a = new ArrayObject("test");
$a->append("unusedVal");` it's the one of my namespace **NamespaceTesting** . my goal is to use the global class ArrayObject, not the one of my namespace.

Comment: It's a combination of changes. You need to remove the use statement. En add the slash in front of the class you are instantiating outside the current used namespace